# Появление untagged метки на вопросах

Tags: поддержка, метки, удаление-метки

Сегодня решил посмотреть, не было ли случайно каких-то пропущенных вопросов по метке [лямбда-исчисление](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). С удивлением обнаружил, что единственный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429595/%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)  с этой меткой, который был задан до этого, пропал из списка.

Через некоторое время смог его найти и увидел вместо прошлой метки новую: [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged), при этом новой записи с редактированием вопроса не создано.

Хотелось бы подробнее узнать о механизме проставления метки [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метки, по которым есть только один вопрос, автосжигаются системой через 6 месяцев.

Если после такого автосожжения или после ручного сожжения модератором на вопросе не остается метки - ему проставляется метка [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

Английская мета: [What causes a question to be tagged as [untagged]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167879/)

Comment: Нужно завести русскоязычный синоним, но так чтобы он устанавливался автоматом.